# How to get all sub/inner/nested Fragments of a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

It looks like it's [possible to get all fragments of an Activity pretty easily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102007/693752). But how can I get all subfragments for a given fragment ?

This question is also related to [getParentFragment API 16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20376297/693752)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same way -- just use the `FragmentManager` obtained using the `Fragment` instance's `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of the `Activity` `FragmentManager`. Of course, this assumes you're using a recompiled version of the support library with `getFragments()` not hidden, or are using reflection to get invoke that method.

Comment: Same way as what ? Moreover, I am looking for some method that will always work, it's not for an app but for a library that should work for all apps.

Comment: Same as the answer you linked to (using getFragments()). I don't believe there's any other way to do so.

Comment: It looks like getFragments got public on support fragment manager, even if javadoc doesn't say so. And yes, using reflection is mandatory for the native fragment manager.

Comment: But this doesn't address the case where I use native (non support) fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not perfect but it works in some extent :

- If Android SDK is 17+, then it works fine
- below SDK 17 it works for fragments at the root level (added directly to activity), and also works fine for fragments of level 1 (added to a fragment at root level).
- for fragments of level >= 2, then it will always return a fragment of root level. It means that it is not possible to return the real parent of a fragment whose level is >=2, it will always return its ancestor at the root level.
- And, unfortunately, it means you must have access to the activity class, so this solution is not really generic.

Here is the solution. The MyActivity class is given below.

```
public static Fragment getParentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        return fragment.getParentFragment();
    MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)fragment.getActivity();
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = activity.getActiveFragments();
    if( fragmentList.contains( fragment) ) {
        return null;
    }
    for( Fragment fragmentLevel1 : fragmentList ) {
        if( fragmentLevel1.getFragmentManager() == fragment.getFragmentManager() ) {
            return fragmentLevel1;
        }
    }
    //this is not supposed to happen, it might be better to throw an exception
    return null;
}
```

Where MyActivity is based on : [Is there a way to get references for all currently active fragments in an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102007/693752)

```
public class MyActivity {
    List<WeakReference<Fragment>> fragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
        fragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
    }

    public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
        ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : fragList) {
            Fragment f = ref.get();
            if(f != null) {
                if(f.isVisible()) {
                    ret.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```